# Static button below Viewpager w/ tabs - Actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

So I'm trying to create a layout such that I would have a viewpager w/tabs at the top of the page, with a couple of static buttons at the bottom that do not move when I swipe across tabs.  Seem to have hit a roadblock though, my fragments don't load and I lose swiping capability when I implement the following code.  I'm new to Actionbarsherlock, not sure what the problem is, would appreciate any help.  Thanks!

The java:

```
public class Main extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

ViewPager mViewPager;
TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;
TextView tabCenter;
TextView tabText;
Menu menu;
SubMenu subMenu1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);

    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);

    mTabsAdapter
            .addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab 1"), Fragment1.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab 2"), Fragment2.class,
            null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab 3"), Fragment3.class,
            null);

}

public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(),
                info.args);
    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
}
```

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="4dip" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```